# Putting lists in a single data frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Suppose we have the following data set named `data2`.

```
id  v1  v2
1   5   0.5
1   4   0.5
1   6   0.5
2   2   0.2
2   3   0.2
2   7   0.2
2   8   0.2
```

The following code:

```
library(doParallel)
un_id <- unique(data2$id)
out <- vector('list', length(un_id))
names(out) <- un_id
registerDoParallel(cl <- makeCluster(length(un_id)))
for(id1 in un_id) {
    subdat <- subset(data2, id == id1)
    out[[id1]] <- foreach(i = nrow(subdat)) %dopar% {
      a <- matrix(nrow = nrow(subdat), ncol=2)
       for (j in 1:nrow(subdat)) {
         for (k in 1:2) {
             a[j,k] <- j*k
          }
        }
        a
     } 
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

produce two `lists`:

```
$`1`
$`1`[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    4
[3,]    3    6
[4,]    4    8

$`2`
$`2`[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    4
[3,]    3    6
[4,]    4    8
```

How I combine this into a single data frame? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Either of these should work assuming you want to bind by row, if not use cbind or bind_cols. Unforutnaly your example isn't easily reproducible though.

```
df <- do.call("rbind", yourdata)

or: 
library(dplyr)
df <- bind_rows(yourdata)
```

**EDIT**

I'm not sure if this is two seperate lists or a list of two data frames, if its two lists you could combine them as below and then use the above

```
lists <- do.call(c, list(list1, list2))
```